# php variables in css

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to use php variables in my .css.
I have change my style.css to style.php and I've add the next code in it:

```
 <?php header("Content-type: text/css");


 $color[0]='#ff0000';
 $color[1]='#00ff00';
 $color[2]='#0000ff';


 $i=rand(0,2);
 ?>
```

Then I'm trying to use this color in a css property. Something like this:

```
 background-color: "<?=$color[$i]?>";
```

When I try to see what happens... nothing happens. If I see on firefox inspector it seems that my code is not changing from php to html.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Where are You putting `background-color: "<?=$color[$i]?>";`?

Comment: Seems to work fine for me - does your server definitely allow shortened PHP tags (`<?`)?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question but have you looked at using a CSS pre-processor like LESS or SASS?

Comment: He's only using the short tag with echo.. <?= .. and that's always valid even if short tag is off in php.ini

Comment: @rdjs It's not even indirectly relevant. :) SASS or LESS compiles the CSS to be static. What (I guess), he's trying to accomplish is that the background color is random on each page load.

Comment: You can do that in SASS & LESS: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922336/random-color-from-array-in-sass / http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17763997/less-css-variable-defined-by-function-multiple-executions

Comment: Bogdan, I put that on my style.php. Magnus, this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson, if the php version is below 5.4 it's a problem if short tags is off

Comment: @swidmann - You are absolutely correct! Sorry about that. I've been living in the 5.4+ world for a while. :)

Answer (score 1):

Use classes on body:

```
<?php 
    $class[0]='red';
    $class[1]='lime';
    $class[2]='blue';
    $i=rand(0,2);
?>

<body class="<?php echo $class[$i]; ?>">

//The result
<body class="red"></body>
<body class="lime"></body>
<body class="blue"></body>
```

Work with inheritances on CSS file:

```
.red .my-another-class{
    background-color: red;
}
.lime .my-another-class{
    background-color: lime;
}
.blue .my-another-class{
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So if you're loading `style.php` as a CSS file you should do this in your `<head>` so it's treated by the browser as such

```
<link href="style.php" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT:**

> I'm trying to use php variables in my .css

You CAN NOT use `php` in `.css` files, your "css" file has to be a php file, look the example above.

In PHP: Just **remove the quotes** from your output:

```
 background-color: <?=$color[$i]?>;
```

If your PHP version is **below 5.4** and [short open tag](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag) is disabled, you have to write it like this:

```
background-color: <?php echo $color[$i] ?>;
```

From the PHP docs:

> **Note:** This directive also affected the shorthand `<?=` before PHP 5.4.0,
>   which is identical to `<?` echo. Use of this shortcut required
>   `short_open_tag` to be on. Since PHP 5.4.0, `<?=` is always available.

***EXAMPLE***

In this example index.html and css.php are on the same level

```
htdocs
   |-- index.html
   |-- css.php
```

**index.html:**

```
<html
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type='text/css' href="css.php" />
    </head>
    <body>
        Sometext
    </body>
</html>
```

**your css.php:**

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
$color[0]='#ff0000';
$color[1]='#00ff00';
$color[2]='#0000ff';


$i=rand(0,2);
?>
body {
    background-color: <?=$color[$i]?>;
}
```

Comment: Why is it not working, how do you use it, can you add your example files to your answer?

Comment: firefox inspector shows me background-color: <?=$color[$i]?>; and not the color inside the variable. And obviously, color does not change...

Comment: If you still have the problems, I would recommend you to update your question, add a small example like I did, I think there is some other error, you can try to change it to `<?php echo $color[$i] ?>`Maybe your PHP version is too old